# How to proceed with this induction step?

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, induction

As a small preface: the following problem is supposed to be homework, so I am looking more for hints than a complete answer. The problem is as follows:

$ \text{Let}\ n \ \text{be a strictly positive integer and}\ x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n\ \text{be real numbers with}\ x_i \geq 1 \ \text{for}\ i = 1, \dots , n$
$$\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + x_i) \geq \frac{2^n}{n + 1} \cdot \left(1 + \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \right)$$

The assignment also adds that this can be proven by induction, but as a challenge, one can even look for a proof without induction. I am unfortunately stuck on how to proceed with the induction step. It is clear to me that both sides are greater than or equal to $2^n$, and I know that I can use the induction hypothesis with $\prod_{i = 1}^{n + 1} (1 + x_i) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} (1 + x_i) \cdot (1 + x_{n + 1})$, but I do not know how to form the desired expression afterwards. A small hint would be very appreciated!

Comment: **Hint**: In a problem like this,there are two distinct standard induction methods for proving that $f(n) \geq g(n), ~\forall ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$  after establishing that $f(1) \geq g(1)$: [1] Show that (in general) $~f(n+1) - f(n) \geq g(n+1) - g(n).~$ [2] Show that (in general) $~\displaystyle \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} \geq \frac{g(n+1)}{g(n)}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your hint, I am still stuck on how to prove either of those relations, but I will continue to try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof without induction looks even simpler:

Let $x_i=1+y_i$, then $y_i \ge 0 \ \forall i$.

The statement can then be reduced to

$$\prod_{i=1}^n\left(2+y_i \right) \ge \frac{2^n}{n+1}\left(n+1+\sum_{i=1}^ny_i \right)$$

$$\iff  \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n\left(2+y_i \right)}{2^n} \ge \frac{1}{n+1}\left(n+1+\sum_{i=1}^ny_i \right)
$$
$$\iff  \prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{y_i}{2} \right) \ge 1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{y_i}{n+1}
$$

and the last statement is easy to prove.

Answer (score 1):

For the induction step, I would like to introduce a more-general inequality: for $0< a\le A$ and $0<b\le B$,

$$\frac{1+A}{1+a}\cdot \frac{1+B}{1+b} \ge \frac{1+A+B}{1+a+b}.$$

Proof by [the mediant inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Properties): First from $\dfrac Aa\ge \dfrac 11$ and $\dfrac Bb\ge \dfrac 11$, we get respectively

$$\frac Aa \ge \frac{1+A}{1+a} \quad \text{and}\quad \frac Bb \ge \frac{1+B}{1+b}.$$

Multiplying the two inequalities and expanding the right-hand side,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{AB}{ab} &\ge \frac{1+A}{1+a}\cdot \frac{1+B}{1+b}\\
&= \frac{AB + (1+A+B)}{ab + (1+a+b)}
\end{align*}$$

The RHS is the mediant of $\dfrac{AB}{ab}$ and $\dfrac{1+A+B}{1+a+b}$ (both have positive numerators and denominators). Again by the mediant inequality, the order between these two fractions and their mediant has to be

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{AB}{ab} \ge \frac{AB + (1+A+B)}{ab + (1+a+b)} &\ge \frac{1+A+B}{1+a+b}\\
\frac{1+A}{1+a} \cdot \frac{1+B}{1+b} &\ge \frac{1+A+B}{1+a+b}
\end{align*}$$

---

Then for the induction step of this question, put:

$$\begin{align*}
A &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i & B &= x_{n+1}\\
a&= n & b &= 1
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n+1} \cdot \frac{1+x_{n+1}}{2} &\ge \frac{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i}{n+2}\\
\frac{2^n}{n+1}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\cdot \left(1+x_{n+1}\right) &\ge \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+2}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i\right)
\end{align*}$$